# Aquaris no more mobile or wifi connectivity

Tags: networking, wireless, ubuntu-touch, phone

My aquaris 4.5 ran without significant problems for 17 months. Today all of a sudden I have no more connectivity to the mobile network nor WiFi. It looks as if those radio devices didn't exist any more. There was no error or even a warning message.

indicator-network is empty

In System settings -> WiFi, there is no more device that I can turn on or off.

Also System settings -> Phone, most of the options are gone.

What I tried so far:

- turned airplane mode on and off a few times
- rebooted the phone a few times
- turned off and waited before turning the phone on again (a few
  times)
- removed the SIM and tried the other slot (back and forth a few
  times)
- the SIM works in another phone

Comment: I would say, try to reset your phone after backing up your necessary data. If the problems persist, your phone might be broken.

Comment: I have had iasues from day 1 with my E5 and mymobile network dropping out and showing full aignal, then when you use iron, it dies. However, I have always in the end got a signal back. What OTA version are you running? A phone reset would be the next course of action. All the actions you mention have worked in the past for me.

Comment: A factory reset made the devices work again. But I'm still in the process of restoring my settings and data. It's especially troubling since I still have to set up the contact sync on the commandline.

Comment: After giving it some more thought, I might have the reason for the failure. On the last day where the devices worked properly, podbird was downloading podcasts. When I got a warnig that the disk filled up, I deleted some files, but maybe it was too late already. That's the only cause I can imagine. But frankly, this should not be allowed to break the phone!

Comment: If it did break the phone,it would be good to know. If it did, like you said it should not. May be worth logging a Launchpad for this.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that a problem in the user config files can cause the network to disappear. The same symptoms on an aquaris E4.5 were solved by

- deleting /home/phablet/.config/connectivity-service/
- reboot

After reboot, the directory was restored by the system and the network was OK again. Before deleting, there were two files in the directory: config.ini and config.ini.lock. After reboot, only config.ini was restored.

What I tried before:

- backup /home/phablet to the SD card using tar -cvz
- factory reset from settings

Result: network was OK

- Copy original /home/phablet back from the tar archive

Result: network still OK, but contacts and app icons not shown. Therefore:

- reboot

Result: The original state was back, everything looked like before the factory reset including the problem that the phone didn't seem to have a network. So I looked into /home/phablet/.config for possible candidates.

What broke the configuration? No idea...

Comment: That is good to hear that you have been able to perform steps to help determine what the issue is and this will give the dev team hopefully something to go on. I will have to download all my pics and then I will follow the steps you mentioned. If you did it again do you need to copy the original /home/phablet or could you just load apps again and then use goofle to sync your contacts?